# UIBarButtonItem appearance iOS5 font

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I am using a little chunk of code like below to change the text attributes of my nav bar title app wide and it works great.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cochin-BoldItalic" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont,
      nil]];
```

But I want to be able to just as easily do this for UIBarButtonItem text as well but I can't figure it out as it doesn't share the same or similar methods it appears.

### Edit

Tried this code, not making any changes to text:

```
[[UIBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cochin-BoldItalic" size:12.0], UITextAttributeFont,
      nil]
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use the `- (void)setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes forState:(UIControlState)state` method of UIBarItem (UIBarButtonItem inherits from UIBarItem).

Check out the docs for more details: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem

Try this:

```
//Suppose you have initialized barButton elsewhere`
[barButton setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cochin-BoldItalic" size:12.0], UITextAttributeFont,
      nil]
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Hmm, hadn't thought of that. Tried it and it compiles and runs which is progress but it isn't changing any attributes of my bar button text! I've added the code Im using in my OP.

Comment: @JoshKahane try what I just posted

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work on iOS 7.1:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                 NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Resamitz" size:16.0]}
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```